# Add Subtitles to HTML5 Videos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5-video

I built a custom HTML5 Video Player with JavaScript, I hide the native controls with the following js code:

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");
video.controls = false;
```

Then I customized the controls (Play - Pause - Fullscreen...) everything worked just fine.
My problem is when I implemented the  tag as shown below:

```
<track label="English" kind="subtitles" src="sub/vid_sub.vtt" srclang="en">
```

The subtitle did not show up, So I figure out that the js code that hid the controls also hid the  tag, I tried to find a way to disable all the native controls except the  tag, But I couldn't.
If there is any way I could fix this please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add default to the html track it will show by default if u want to manipulate multiple subtitles you can queryselect them all then show the one user clicked on as follow.

```
for (var i = 0; i < video.textTracks.length; i++) {
    if (video.textTracks[i].language == 'en') {
        video.textTracks[i].mode = 'showing';
 }
```

if you want to hide it just as follows.

```
track.mode="hidden";
```